# Converting golfed (200 character) Ruby Code to functionally equivalent simplified JAVA code

Tags: java, ruby, pascals-triangle

**I need a simplified (Pseudo/C++/JAVA) version of this Ruby code -**

```
def P(a)a.min<0?0:a.max<1?1:(b=a*1;t=k=0;b.map{b[k]-=1;k+=1;t+=P(b)};t)end
def d(n,a)print n>1?((0..a[-1]).map{|i|d(n-1,a+[i])};"\n"):"#{P(a)} "end
d(ARGV[0].to_i,[ARGV[1].to_i])
```

For context, please visit [Code golf- Pascal's pyramid and higher dimensions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2741/pascals-pyramid-and-higher-dimensions/2742#2742?newreg=4881b3b4ca164fdb97483a56593e2bda)

Here is what I have so far,
**Pseudo code**-

```
/**
*   This prints out one 'row', specified by indices in array
*   for Pascal's triangle of the given dimension
**/
void doit(int dimension, list array){
    if(dimension>1){
        for(int i=0;i<=array.lastElement();++i){
            // Recursively call function with reduced dimension and
            // extended array (count index appended)
            doit(dimension-1, array.append(i));
        }
        print a newline;
    }
    else{
        print Pascal(a);
    }
}

/**
*   This calculates a specific entry in the Pascal's triangle
**/
int Pascal(list array){
    // Pascal(...,-1,...) = 0
    if(minimum(array)<0){
        return 0;
    }
    // Pascal(0,0,...,0) = 1
    else if(maximum(array)<1){
        return 1;
    }
    // Pascal(a,b,c,...) = Pascal(a-1,b,c,...) + Pascal(a-1,b-1,c,...) + Pascal(a-1,b-1,c-1,....)
    else{
        list work_array = array.copy();
        int result = 0;

        for(int i=0;i<work_array.length;++i){
            // Decrement i'th element in array
            work_array[i] = work_array[i]-1;
            // Recursively call this function with modified array
            // and add return value to result.
            result = result + Pascal(work_array);
        }

        return result;
    }
}

void main(firstArg, secondArg){
    doit(firstArg.toInt(), new list [secondArg.toInt()]);
}
```

**Implementation of above Pseudo Code in JAVA**-

```
import java.util.*;
public class Pascal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> power=new ArrayList<Integer>();
        power.add(3);
        doit(4,power);

    }

    public static void doit(int dimension, ArrayList<Integer> array){
        if(dimension>1){
            for(int i=0;i<=(int) array.get(array.size() - 1);++i){
                array.add(i);
                doit(dimension-1,array);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        else{
            System.out.print(Pa(array));
        }
    }

    public static int Pa(ArrayList<Integer> array){
        if((int)Collections.min(array) <0){
            return 0;
        }
        else if((int)Collections.max(array) <1){
            return 1;
        }
        else{
            ArrayList<Integer> work_array = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            //Collections.copy(work_array, array);
            for(int i=0;i<array.size();i++){
                work_array.set(i, array.get(i));
            }
            int result=0;
            for(int i=0;i<work_array.size();++i){
                work_array.set(i, work_array.get(i)-1);
                result=result+Pa(work_array);
            }
            return result;
        }
    }

}
```

But this does not give the same output, it shows an error-

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0   at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)   at java.util.ArrayList.set(Unknown Source)  at Pascal.Pa(Pascal.java:35)    at Pascal.doit(Pascal.java:20)  at Pascal.doit(Pascal.java:15)  at Pascal.main(Pascal.java:7)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why is this tagged C++ as well? You have written Java code so far. Pick one language and not the other for now.

Comment: @hexafraction Ok. Will remove C++ then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have any elements in your `ArrayList<Integer> work_array = new ArrayList<Integer>();` therefore your index ist [out of range](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#set%28int,%20E%29), since the  `size()` returns 0.

Comment: Initialized work_array with a value of 1, still the same error.

Comment: The default constructor initializes the the ArrayList with size 10 (the data structure is backed by an array of that size). You need to actually have some elements in the List in order to avoid the error, since otherwise the size() method will return 0 and your index ("i") will always be "index >= size()" (check the javadoc link in the answer). In your code, you might just use the .add() method since you just add elements from 0 till work_array.size().

Comment: .add() worked. But that wasn't the only problem. When recursively calling the doit function, I was passing the same array but what was needed was to keep that unchanged and pass a new temporary array for every new call.